# List of jQuery image editors

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Do you know good image editors in jQuery? With basic functionality, like cropping, resizing, rotating, adding a watermark etc.

So far I've seen [jCrop](http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php) which I think is really nice.

Are there any other good plugins out there for image manipulation that fit these criteria?

Comment: This question is better suited for a chat room or possibly http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a decent list of jQuery plugins, including image editors, check out [www.webappers.com](http://www.webappers.com)

Comment: Can you please specify which one is the best

Comment: I personally integrate pixlr into my sites. It's like an online Photoshop that you allow your users to work within and then pull back the results into your application.

http://pixlr.com/developer/include

Answer (score 2):

Photo Editor by Aviary
it's a solid one and have a lot of options 
also have API for development

here : [aviary](http://www.aviary.com/)

Alos there is this collection of JS plugins of Images manipulate found it here

[Js Images manipulate](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/image-manipulation/)